# Is there one DOM, or is each append to html a new one?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a site where the page loads images and description into the DOM.

e.g.

```
html += '<div class="className">';
html += '<img src="/path/to/image.jpg><a href="link.html">more info</a>';
html += '</div>';
```

Now, we are able to monetize some of the clicks on the links and use a company called Skimlinks to process this.

Because we are loading the potential monetizable (sp?) links into the DOM, their code must be added into the DOM `skimlinks();` simple enough.

Now, sometimes there maybe 100 results of a search and we show the results in batches of 30 at a time, then preload the next results, then when user clicks **show more** we then append the html again and add the new content.

**QUESTION:** Is the new content being loaded into the same DOM (meaning is there more than one) as the first results and therefore as I've already called `skimlinks();` so all is good, or, do I have to call `skimlinks();` with every new addition.

I know this question may also need to be aimed at them, but I'm also interested in how things work when added to the DOM.

Comment: Just to be certain I understand your question, you're asking if the effects of the `skimlinks();` call are applied to new DOM elements as they are appended without calling `skimlinks()` again?

Comment: @DanHerbert Exactly that Dan, summed up perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There's only a single DOM tree (single document), unless you start using `iframes`. Each `iframe` has its own document. Now, for `skimlinks`, it depends on their implementation. If they attached a click event handler directly on the whole document, you will not have to call it again, but if they are attaching a click handler on each individual links, the new links that you add to the DOM will not be handled.

Comment: Thanks for that, thats a great way for me to investigate.